# webengine crash on Javafx 2.2.25

Tags: html, javafx

I am finding a issue when loading a html file in javafx using webEngine. 
But in my case if i use java update 9 everything works fine but when i use any update after that like java update 25 with javafx version 2.2.25 ... the app crashes with EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006e103b24, pid=7644, tid=8180.

here is what i am trying to do:

```
WebView webView = new WebView();



webEngine = webView.getEngine();    

JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window"); // Crashes at this point but everything works fine with older version of java fx.
window.setMember("javafx", baseui);
scene = new Scene(webView, 1000, 800);

primaryStage = stage;
stage.setScene(scene);

stage.show();
stage.setIconified(true);


             webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
             new ChangeListener<State>(){
             @Override
             public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                 if(newState == State.SUCCEEDED){
                     JSObject window = (JSObject)webEngine.executeScript("window");
                     window.setMember("javafx", baseui);                     
                 }
             }
             });

URL urlHello = getClass().getResource("*.html"); // My HTML file
webEngine.load(urlHello.toExternalForm());
```

I tried solutions in this post like Platform.RunLater but of no help.
Is this bug fixed?? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
nitin

Comment: This might be related to https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-40490 (you have to be logged in to see actual ticket). Unfortunatelly it will be fixed in http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8u/releases/8u60.html which is scheduled for September 2015.